# Does adding an empty string give any benefit?

Tags: sql-server, varchar

Today I found the following SQL expression:

```
WHERE MyColumn = '' + @var1 + @var2 + ''
```

Both variables and the column are defined as `varchar`.

Do the empty string provide any benefit?  I can't see how any of the variables could contain anything other than text or `null`.

Comment: It might be a convenience if the developer wanted to add additional characters at the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no benefit to doing that in string concatenation. aside from possibly ensuring that `@var1` and `@var2` are always implicitly converted to string to ensure no numeric addition occurs, but there are better ways to do that. Are those variables defined as a particular datatype?

Comment: He mentioned it clearly in the question **Both variables and the column are defined as varchar**

Comment: Heh, I even read that, but I typed that question out as an afterthought and realized it as I hit submit. The variables may have been typed differently in a previous iteration of the script and the query was just never updated.